# SSH - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I know this question has been asked many times and I have tried the top answers from all of them, but I still can't get mine to work.  It says that files like `/home/valachio/.ssh/id_rsa` are not found but I checked my server and all the files are clearly there.

I tried using a generated SSH key with `ssh-keygen` and also tried using an SSH key generated with PuTTY.  The SSH key is correctly stored in `authorized_keys` under `/home/valachio/.ssh/`.  I checked the format of the key, and it should be correct.  It `ssh-rsa (keyname) valachio@(myserverhost)`

When I do `ssh -vT valachio@159.203.13.88`, the error message is:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 159.203.13.88 [159.203.13.88] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/valachio/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/valachio/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/valachio/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/valachio/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/valachio/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/valachio/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/valachio/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/valachio/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 159.203.13.88:22 as 'valachio'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Cb+ahYzmTapn99cB5mA+V3T165RkGAItyxV3kYGgOF4
debug1: Host '159.203.13.88' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/valachio/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/valachio/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/valachio/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/valachio/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/valachio/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

If someone can help decipher what the error message is saying and give me some pointers, that will be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify where you find those files in the question. You need `id_rsa` on the **client** (you stated you find it on a **server**, I doubt whether it is a typo or you really only did `ssh-keygen` on the server and nothing else. If it is the latter case, it certainly won't work) and the data of `id_rsa.pub` stored in the `authorized_keys` on the **server**. Also check permissions as others have stated.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the public key, `id_rsa.pub`. Here is an example generation of a public and private key pair on a server.

```
 $ ls -ltrh .ssh/
 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 394 Jul 18 23:49 known_hosts

 $ ssh-keygen  -t rsa
 Generating public/private rsa key pair.

 Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): Enter passphrase 
 (empty for no passphrase): 
 Enter same passphrase again: 
 Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
 Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
 The key fingerprint is:
 SHA256:allgibberishnosecutiryjustfakingit root@localhost
 ....
  blah blah...
 ... blah

 $ ls -ltrh .ssh/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  394 Jul 18 23:49 known_hosts
-rw-------  1 root root 1.7K Jan 12 22:13 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  395 Jan 12 22:13 id_rsa.pub
```

Next step is to copy the `id_rsa.pub` to the remote server file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and then retry the `ssh -vv` command.

Comment: I just spent a billion years struggling with this error trying to get ssh to work between two virtual machines... only to find out that the whole key-gen and public key sharing process has to happen on BOTH machines.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the ownership of 'id_rsa' and the permissions of both the '.ssh' directory and the 'id_rsa' file.   Make sure 'valachio' owns both of those.  Then make sure '.ssh' has 700 permissions, and 'id_rsa' has 600.